# How to get more the one value of the same key using Java

Tags: java, json

I'm receiving an JSON String in my Server which has only two parameters: name and number. Find example below:

```
{"name":"outlet.jpg","numbar":"2"},{"name":"image.jpg","number":"3"}, {"name":"testing.jpg","number":"1"}
```

I'm trying to unpack this values in a String Array. How can I do it?

This is what I have so far:

```
JSONObject jsonObject;

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length()-1));
            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            String number = jsonObject.getString("number");
            System.out.println("nome: " + name + " number: " + number);
        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There's no getString() in jsonObject which returns an Array. 
This example is only getting the first element of the JSON String.. How can I receive an String Array for each key of JSON String?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, an array in JSON must begin and end with [], are you removing them with the `jsonString.substring` code?

Comment: What are you trying to unpack into an array, the "name" values or the "numbar" ones?

Comment: Also take a look at this class: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Yeah, cause I was getting an JSONObject exception saying my JSON String should start with { .. that's why I used substring

Comment: I'm trying to unpack both of them.. but which one in a diferent String Array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong type. What you want is a [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29).

This JSON:

```
[{"name":"outlet.jpg","number":"2"},{"name":"image.jpg","number":"3"}, {"name":"testing.jpg","number":"1"}]
```

And this code:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int index = 0; index < json.length(); index++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(index);
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    String number = jsonObject.getString("number");
    System.out.println("name: " + name + " number: " + number);
}
```

Should produce this output:

```
name: outlet.jpg number: 2
name: image.jpg number: 3
name: testing.jpg number: 1
```